# How to pan, zoom and orbit using keyboard AND mouse button?

Tags: shortcut, settings

I am switching from Cinema4D where pan, zoom and orbit is realised by using

key 1 + left mouse button
key 2 + left mouse button
key 3 + left mouse button

I can not figure out how to set this up in blender. I am unable to combine left mouse button with a keystroke.

Can anybody help please?
Thanks in advance!

Michael

Comment: Is that "keys" are ctrl shift and alt? If it so, try Industry Standard keymap

Comment: Sorry, no ctrl shift and alt.I would like to pan by holding "1" on the keyboard (not numpad) and holding the left mouse button. For zoom I want to hold "2" on the keyboard and click the left mouse button. For orbiting holding "3" on the keyboard and clicking the left mouse button. I tried the Industry Standard settings, but they don't work for me.

Comment: I've tried to set this as you want, and the problem that Blender doesn't allow to set number as modifier. You can set keys (A-Z) or Numpad keys or functional keys (F1-F12) but not the numbers from the numbers row. I'm sure that it is a bug, i will report it

Answer (score 2):

Try:

1. Click *Edit > Preferences*.
2. Click *Keymap* (left side).
3. Click the top drop-down.
4. Change "Blender" to "Industry Compatible".

   [image: Blender Settings]

Do these defaults match your preferences?

If not, from this menu you can go in and manually change them all by searching for your function in the search bar (Zoom, Orbit etc.) then changing the key binding from there.

Comment: I know where to change the keybindings but I can not figure out how to combine left mouse button with "1" on the keyboard for example...

Comment: I now have figured out how to combine a keystroke with left mouse button click: just click and type alltogether... it doesn't work before, due to the fact that Blender doesn't accept the key "1" in combination with left mouse button for some reason. Does anybody know which three keys besides each other (like 1, 2, 3 or STRG, Windows, alt) are free for use?

Comment: @lockehl, yes, that's something I also discovered. The only buttons it will access in this context are the typical modifier keys - ctrl, shift and alt. On Mac, cmd is also useable. IIRC, it's often interchangeable with ctrl (especially for common commands like ctrl-z)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to set this as you want, and the problem that Blender doesn't allow to set number as modifier. You can set keys (A-Z) or Numpad keys or functional keys (F1-F12) but not the numbers from the numbers row. So I decided to raise a bug report, and it has been fixed: https://developer.blender.org/T95078

You will be able to do it in Blender 3.1 or tomorrow build

Comment: Thank you so much, Crantisz. I am looking forward to install the new version to use it!