# when I zoom in or out the xyz location effect with increasing and decreasing,

Tags: snapping

I just want to stick with the number 4 meter with the axis if I zoom in or out[image]

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. You talk about zooming in/out, but pressing `G` moves an object... so it's not very surprising the location changes when you move it.

Comment: Do you mean you just want to zoom in?  Have you tried this looking to this.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250543/how-to-pan-zoom-and-orbit-using-keyboard-and-mouse-button

Comment: Bearing in mind Blender's viewport 'zoom' is actually a dolly. To zoom: N-panel > View tab: 'Focal Length'